# Can I explode my mesh in Blender?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Is there a modifier or a quick way to explode a complex mesh in Blender?

In order to be as clear as i can, when I write explode, I mean:

[image: image description]

Comment: Is each component a separate object?

Comment: Yes it is. Every single part of my mesh (not the one in the gif, that is an example finded on youtube) is a separate object

Comment: Did you want your object to explode or create something like an exploded drawing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you will do to start with is add a rigid body simulation to one of your objects and set it to *active*. You can do this in the *Toolshelf*, or in the *Physics tab*.

[image]

Then, in order to have the objects react to each other in close proximity. use the *collision margin* option. Adjust this to be as high as needed. The maximum is 1.0. If this needs to be animated, you can keyframe this as well.

[image]

Next, select all objects that compose the model being exploded, or rather that should share the same rigid body properties that you just made. I sometimes find it to be faster to take advantage of *wireframe* here to quickly select anything behind with border selection. Now, with everything selected go to the *toolshelf>physics* and select *copy from active* to copy the physics settings to all selected objects.   It is a good idea to remember to do this anytime you change the simulation or you may have an unexpected result.

[image]

After you have done this, head over to the scene properties, and you can *bake* the rigid body simulation.

[image]

[image]

I just used a sphere after a cell fracture as an example, but this works with anything else also that is made of separate objects. You may also find it necessary to adjust the *mass* of objects in the rigid body settings.

[image]

Comment: What you explain is making the object explode. What is asked in the question looks to me like an exploded view or exploded drawing, a kind of technical schematics where a complex object is shown with its parts spacially separated to give a clear overview. But anyway, the OP accepted this answer so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Randomize Transform will achieve this.

*Object>Transform>Randomize Transform.*

Make sure to uncheck *Randomize Scale* and *Rotation* and pick through random seeds to get different results.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about it too, and I found a pair of solutions:

1- Using the option Locations and scale the objects in the desired direction:
I share you the tutorial I found about the guy explaining it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9GYrjhjtdo

2- Use option Explode of TexTools Addon. It will try to create an explode vision at frame 50 of our selected objects. Take in consideration the names of the objects, if they are not different they will not explode, and you have to be in frame 0.

https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender

I hope it helps! (: